# 2005 ford f150 5.4 triton

Tags: electrical, ford, electronics

I have acquired through an auction a 2005 f150 FX4 with a triton 5.4 engine. It has sat indoors idle for about nine(9) years. Cab corners are the only body issue. Battery has gone dead at some unknown date possibly been dead for 6-7 years. My question is what will happen to the CPU and other modules on the vehicle? Will I need to get everything re-flashed? I changed out the battery and have some but not all electrical working, I have not gone through the fuse panel yet. I am not worried about the engine being seized etc that is an obvious condition to work on. What do I have to worry about regarding the electronics? Thanks for your responses.
ArtM

Comment: What electrical works and what does not? "Some" is very difficult to narrow down to a fuse or component...

Comment: Since I don't know anything about the F150 in particular I'll let someone else make a proper answer. However it would be quite a bad design if it didn't handle long periods of no power.
But have you thought about mice and other critters? The like cables.

Comment: the radio works, power seats work. windows not working heater fan not working will not turn over and cannot hear solenoid cycling so not aware yet if engine is seized.

Comment: I am just wondering if there is something I should pay particular attention too when I do start the systematic look at all wiring etc. I have not started yet it's been to cold minus 10 to 20 last couple of weeks. I intend to do a hand turn over of the engine before I use a starter just to see if it requires other work to get it to turn over. I want to clean up the engine compartment and pull the plugs and put some fluids in the cylinders to loosen things up and provide some lube. I am moving one step at a time covering all bases to work it all out.

Comment: "Will I need to get everything re-flashed?" No.

Comment: "What do I have to worry about regarding the electronics?" If it was stored in a relatively dry environment you should not have any major issues.

Comment: perfect that is what I was suspecting and hoping to hear.I am sure this whole thing will be a systematic system by system trouble shooting exercise to make sure everything is correct and operational.